# Adminlte fixed layout without fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css, adminlte

So im using Adminlte with a fixed layout. The thing is I only wanted the sidebar fixed and not the header. So I removed the position: fixed from the main header.

The problem - when scrolling down there is a gap (the size of header) at the top of the sidebar.

[image]

I tried this at first :

```
.fixed .main-sidebar{
   padding-top:0;
}
```

But the problem is if you don't scroll past the heading completely the sidebar jumps under it.

[image]

So now I added a function in js to calculate the position and add padding accordingly. Its kinda working but its laggy and probably a bad solution.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

     var positionNow = $(window).scrollTop();

     if (positionNow < 50){
         $('.fixed .main-sidebar').css({"padding-top" : 50 - positionNow});
     } else {
         $('.fixed .main-sidebar').css({"padding-top" : "0"});
         $('.main-sidebar').css({"padding-top" : "0"});
     }

  });
```

Is there a better way to make the sidebar jump to top?

*I realized that the gap is showing because the class main-sidebar includes the logo at top. But making the class .sidebar fixed weirdly doesn't affect sidebar-collapse.*

Comment: is it necessary to have your heading ontop of your sidenav, if not you can try giving your sidenav a higher z-index

Comment: Um no.. I want it to have padding : 0 relative to the heading if the heading is visible and if not then at the top of the page.

Comment: can u provide code of the header and sidenav, how does the header get visible and hidden, how does the sidenav behave

Comment: you can build a function if your header is :hidden $('.fixed .main-sidebar') gets padding-top 0

Comment: Oh that fixed functionality is built in Adminlte. i just had to add class fixed to body..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two very simple way to achieve this

1. Remove `fixed` class from body(**Note: It will make sidebar scrollable**) or
2. Add css property `position: absolute` in `main-header` class

   `.main-header {
      position: absolute !important;
   }`

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Why remove the fixed class from body if I need the sidebar fixed ?

Comment: @sasq If you want sidebar fixed then just follow second step.

Comment: wow, it works. can't believe it was this simple. messes up the header tho, now it's shrunk to like half of the page horizontally, but i'll try and fix that. Other than that it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

or you can simply add "**fixed**" to your body on main.php

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini fixed">
```